# ¿Como puedo re-calcular un numero en una tabla, si se agrega mas detalles?

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, dom

[image: <code>introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí</code>]

```
introducir el código aquí
var SumaTotalCotizacionGenerales = function(){
//Obtengo la última fila ingresada en la tabla
var cotizaciongenerales = $("#gastos_totales_generales");
var valor1 = cotizaciongenerales.find('input[type="text"]:eq(0)');
var valor2 = cotizaciongenerales.find('input[type="text"]:eq(1)');
var total_costo_general = cotizaciongenerales.find('input[type="text"]:eq(2)');

valor1.on('change', function(){
  total_costo_general.val(parseInt(valor1.val())*parseInt(valor2.val())/100);
});
valor2.on('change', function(){
  total_costo_general.val(parseInt(valor2.val())*parseInt(valor1.val())/100);  
});
};
SumaTotalCotizacionGenerales();


introducir el código aquí 
<div class="caja8">
<div class="alcance">
<h1>GASTOS GENERALES</h1> 
</div>
<div class="container theme-showcase" role="main">
<br>
<div class="form-group">
<table class='table table-bordered table-hover' id="gastos_totales_generales">
<tr>
                <th>DESCRIPCION</th>
                <th>PORCENTAJE</th>
                <th>SUB TOTAL</th>
                <th>TOTAL</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>GASTOS GENERALES</th>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="porcentaje_gasto_generales" id="porcentaje_gasto_generales" value="<?php echo $power['porcentaje_gastos_general'];?>" ></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="sub_total_gasto_generales"  id="sub_total_gasto_generales" value="<?php echo $power['sub_total_gasto_general'];?>" readonly></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="total_gasto_generales" id="total_gasto_generales" value="<?php echo $power['total_gasto_general'];?>" readonly></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>UTILIDAD</th>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="porcentaje_utilidad" id="porcentaje_utilidad" value="<?php echo $power['porcentaje_utilidad_general'];?>"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="sub_total_utilidad"  id="sub_total_utilidad"  value="<?php echo $power['sub_total_utilidad_general'];?>" readonly></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="total_utilidad"      id="total_utilidad" value="<?php echo $power['total_utilidad_general'];?>" readonly></td>
            </tr>

        </table>                 
    </div>  
</div>
```

```
introducir el código aquí 
var sumaTotalGeneral = function(){
//Inicializo en 0 el valor a establecer indicando el resultado de la sumatoria
var totalgeneralsuma0 = 0;
var totalgeneralsuma1 = 0;
var totalgeneralsuma2 = 0;
//Recorro todas las filas de la tabla
$('tr','#tablaDetalleMaterialEinsumo').each(function(){
 //Obtengo el campo del cual quiero tomar el valor para sumarlo
 var campo_total0 = $(this).find('input[type="text"]:eq(4)');
 //Agrego a totales el nuevo valor
 var numero0 = parseInt(campo_total0.val()); 
 totalgeneralsuma0 += isNaN(numero0) ? 0 : numero0; 
 });


 $('tr','#tablaDetallePersonaEmaquina').each(function(){
 //Obtengo el campo del cual quiero tomar el valor para sumarlo
 var campo_total2 = $(this).find('input[type="text"]:eq(5)');
 //Agrego a totales el nuevo valor
 var numero1 = parseInt(campo_total2.val()); 
 totalgeneralsuma1 += isNaN(numero1) ? 0 : numero1; 
 });

 $('tr','#tablaDetalleGastoGeneral').each(function(){
 //Obtengo el campo del cual quiero tomar el valor para sumarlo
 var campo_total3 = $(this).find('input[type="text"]:eq(4)');
 //Agrego a totales el nuevo valor
 var numero2 = parseInt(campo_total3.val()); 
 totalgeneralsuma2 += isNaN(numero2) ? 0 : numero2; 
 });


 var to= totalgeneralsuma0+totalgeneralsuma1+totalgeneralsuma2;
 //Establezco el resultado de la suma
 $('#sub_total_gasto_generales').val(to);
 };


introducir el código aquí 
function funcNuevaDetallePersonaEmaquina() 
{
$("#tablaDetallePersonaEmaquina")
.append
(
$('<tr>')
.append
(
  $('<td>')
  .append
  (
    $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'detalle_personal_maquina[]')
    )
  )
.append
(
  $('<td>')
  .append
  (
    $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'cantidad_detalle_persona[]')
    )
  )
.append
(
  $('<td>')
  .append
  (
    $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'horas_unitarias_persona[]')
    )
  )
.append
(
 $('<td>')
 .append
 (
  $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'total_horas_persona[]').prop('readonly', true)
  )
 )
.append
(
 $('<td>')
 .append
 (
  $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'valor_unit_persona[]')
  )
 )
.append
(
 $('<td>')
 .append
 (
  $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'valor_total_HH_persona[]').prop('readonly', true)
  )
 )
.append
(
  $('<td>').addClass('text-center')

  .append
  (
    $('<div>').addClass('btn btn-warning').text('Eliminar')
    )            
  )      
);
```

Comment: Deberías agregar tu `HTML`.

Comment: y lo que quiere lograr es que al cambiar el porcentaje o el valor, se calcule el total?

Comment: exacto @Michael, porque cuando agrego una cantidad x de items que da como sub total por ejemplo 2000 y saco el porcentaje me da el resultado correcto, pero si agrego despues mas items y me da como total 2500 con el mismo porcentaje no me realiza el calculo. no se si me comprendes. saludos

Comment: y si solo llama `SumaTotalCotizacionGenerales();` cada que agrega un item nuevo?

Comment: @Michael igual no pasa nada, yo pienso que tiene que ver con el readonly, pero aun no he sido capaz de resolver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pruebe con llamar a `SumaTotalCotizacionGenerales();` cada que agregue un nuevo ITEM pero a su `function` quitele los `on.change` así:

```
var SumaTotalCotizacionGenerales = function(){
   //Obtengo la última fila ingresada en la tabla
   var cotizaciongenerales = $("#gastos_totales_generales");
   var valor1 = cotizaciongenerales.find('input[type="text"]:eq(0)');
   var valor2 = cotizaciongenerales.find('input[type="text"]:eq(1)');
   var total_costo_general = cotizaciongenerales.find('input[type="text"]:eq(2)');

  total_costo_general.val(parseInt(valor1.val())*parseInt(valor2.val())/100);

};
```

(debe de quitar los `on.change` ya que estos no se ejecutan hasta que no cambie el `input` por lo tanto con llamar a la `function` no realizaria el calculo).

para que cada que llame a esa `function` realize el calculo y no espere un cambio en los input para ejecutar el calculo.

Ahora los `on.change` lo único que harían seria llamar a esta función, puede usar el `onchange` he `HTML` para este caso:

```
<input  type="text" 
        class="form-control" 
        name="porcentaje_gasto_generales"
        onchange="SumaTotalCotizacionGenerales()" <!--Así-->
        value=10
        id="porcentaje_gasto_generales">
```

Ejemplo:

```js
var SumaTotalCotizacionGenerales = function() {
  //Obtengo la última fila ingresada en la tabla
  var cotizaciongenerales = $("#gastos_totales_generales");
  var valor1 = cotizaciongenerales.find('input[type="text"]:eq(0)');
  var valor2 = cotizaciongenerales.find('input[type="text"]:eq(1)');
  var total_costo_general = cotizaciongenerales.find('input[type="text"]:eq(2)');
  
  total_costo_general.val(parseInt(valor1.val()) * parseInt(valor2.val()) / 100);
  
/*  valor1.on('change', function() {
    total_costo_general.val(parseInt(valor1.val()) * parseInt(valor2.val()) / 100);
  });
  valor2.on('change', function() {
    total_costo_general.val(parseInt(valor2.val()) * parseInt(valor1.val()) / 100);
  });*/
};


SumaTotalCotizacionGenerales();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="caja8">
 <div class="alcance">
  <h1>GASTOS GENERALES</h1> 
 </div>
 <div class="container theme-showcase" role="main">
 <br>
 <div class="form-group">
  <table class='table table-bordered table-hover' id="gastos_totales_generales">
   <tr>
                <th>DESCRIPCION</th>
                <th>PORCENTAJE</th>
                <th>SUB TOTAL</th>
                <th>TOTAL</th>
         </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>GASTOS GENERALES</th>
                <td>
                 <input  type="text" 
                   class="form-control" 
                   name="porcentaje_gasto_generales"
                      onchange="SumaTotalCotizacionGenerales()"
                      value=10 
                   id="porcentaje_gasto_generales">
                </td>
                <td>
                 <input  type="text" 
                   class="form-control" 
                   name="sub_total_gasto_generales"
                      onchange="SumaTotalCotizacionGenerales()"
                      value=12000 
                   id="sub_total_gasto_generales">
                </td>
                <td>
                 <input  type="text" 
                   class="form-control" 
                   name="total_gasto_generales" 
                   id="total_gasto_generales">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>UTILIDAD</th>
                <td>
                 <input  type="text"
                   class="form-control" 
                   name="porcentaje_utilidad" 
                   id="porcentaje_utilidad">
                </td>
                <td>
                 <input  type="text"
                   class="form-control" 
                   name="sub_total_utilidad" 
                    id="sub_total_utilidad">
                </td>
                <td>
                 <input  type="text"
                   class="form-control" 
                   name="total_utilidad" 
                        id="total_utilidad">
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>                 
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Pruebe con el ejemplo.

Comment: -.-" Supongo que std tiene otra `function` que suma los totales de todos los items cuando agrega uno nuevo, y esa suma la pone en SUB TOTAL, no? o como hace llegar los valores a los `input`?

Comment: por eso, entonces cuando envíe la suma total, llame a `SumaTotalCotizacionGenerales();` para que haga el calculo...

Comment: Tiene que definir una estructura, y luego si el ' script'  para q no de tanta vuelta

Comment: hay agregue la funcion que ocupo para generar nuevas columna